# Bootstrap 4 spacing

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, frontend

New to bootstrap. I have this HTML below. How do I get even spacing between all my box elements without making any of them wrap when on laptop / desktop screens? I did this before using CSS-grid. But I am required to use bootstrap 4 now. I created a grid inside of a grid for my main content. (the right side of the screen) I want all those elements to have even spacing around all 4 sides. I will eventual put a 2 column row underneath the first row in the nested grid. thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Basic HTML File</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        .header {
            background: pink;
        }
        .sidebar {
            background: gray;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .content {
            background: lightgrey;
            height: 100%;
        }
        .box-1 {
            background: coral;
        }
        .box-2 {
            background: aquamarine;
        }
        .box-3 {
            background: darkkhaki;
        }
        .box-4 {
            background: cornflowerblue;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid h-100">

    <div class="row" style="height: 80px;">
        <div class="col header">header</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-3 col-lg-2 sidebar h-100">sidebar</div>
        <div class="col-9 col-lg-10 content h-100">
            <div class="row h-25 boxes">
                <div class="col-3 box-1">
                    box1
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 box-2">
                    box2
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 box-3">
                    box3
                </div>
                <div class="col-3 box-4">
                    box-4
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without just adjusting the padding, you probably have to hack it a bit like [this mdbootstrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/snippets/jquery/milkytech/2207228).

```
div.h-25>div {
  margin-left: 1.333333333333%;
}

div.h-25 > div:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.col-3 {
  max-width: 24%;
}
```